# Кавычить или нет длинное перечисление задаваемых "себе" вопросов?

Tags: кавычки, несобственно-прямая-речь

> ...Роль гносиса заключалась в ответах на извечные вопросы: Кто мы? Кем
>   стали? Где мы? Куда стремимся? Как высвобождаемся?

Как ещё можно оформить? Неужто понижать каждый вопрос? О_о

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..**Роль гносиса заключалась в ответах на извечные вопросы: кто мы? кем стали? где мы? куда стремимся? как высвобождаемся?**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Примечание. Вопросительный знак может ставиться в вопросительном предложении после каждого однородного члена с целью расчленения вопроса: Что я — попугай? индейка? (М.); Кравцов ласково улыбался — его нетерпению? самомнению? гениальности? (Гран.)

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103

Однако прописные буквы заменяются строчными, если перед перечислением стоят знаки двоеточие или тире (впереди имеется обобщение): Всё отвергал: законы! совесть! веру! (Гр.); 
Она спросила, кто он, не француз ли, и стала по его просьбе гадать: бельгиец? датчанин? голландец? (Наб.);

Comment: Угу! Мне нравится! Мерсю!